# How do I make a button disappear and replace itself with another button in swift?

Tags: swift, function, button

I am new to programming and I decided to start by using Swift in Xcode.
I am currently stuck and I don't know how to proceed.

I want to use a button that once pressed will write a determinate sentence in a label and also disappear and replace itself with a new button that will allow me to do a new function. this is basically the whole purpose of the app. In fact, the second button will do the same thing: add a sentence to the label and disappear leaving a place for another button.

This is what I have so far:

```
@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!

@IBAction func button1(sender: UIButton) {
    testo.text = ("ciao" + "\n" + testo.text)
    button1.hidden = true
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many buttons are we talking about here? Why do they have to be different instances of a button? Why can't you re-use a single button and change the appearance / text of the button each time?

Comment: I would love to use a single button and change its function, I am really new to this so I thought that was impossible. but if it is possible that would make everything easier!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the text to be displayed ahead, you could create an array and go through this array with each tap

create variable for click count and array properties

```
var clickCount: Int!
var dataArr: Array<String>!
```

Populate an array with data

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dataArr: Arr = ["Message 1", "Message 2", "Message 3"]
    clickCount = 0
}
```

And finally use your method to update the text in your label

```
@IBAction func button1(sender: UIButton) {

// handle array size
    if clickCount < dataArr.count {

        let textFromArray = String(dataArr[clickCount])
        testo.text = ("ciao" + "\n" + textFromArray)

        // increment count
        clickCount += 1
    }
    else {
    // do something if all items from array were exhausted
        testo.text = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was thinking that if I did use your way it would become really big and complex after a while. Because I want a seres of buttons that lead to different tasks everytime. as Shim suggested I would rather have a single button and change its function and title if that is possible. thanks again!

Comment: That's essentially what is being suggested here

Comment: Understand. You can still use the method above and store the titles of each button in the array. With each click count you change the title...

Comment: Thank you for your support. Would that work even if I want to make that lets say button a and b are present at first, if I press a it shows c and d (and removes b), but if i press b it shows e and f (removing a). and again from those buttons you have other options. imagine it like a pyramid that just doubles the options depending on which path you take, but the options are always 2 (sometimes I want up to 4). Would that be possible by using the array? Be patient with me, I started to learn this yesterday :)

Comment: Hm, pyramid cascade? It looks like some kind of quiz type thing. I am not sure if I understand it properly, but it looks like you will always display 2 options. That means you could use 2 arrays - each for one button - arrayA & arrayB. It's hard to guess, it'll be easier if we will see the design of the cascade with possible answers. Then you could create the custom logic to it..can you draw some?